# Mapping JSON properties to HTML ID to Easily Set Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Assuming I have something like the following:

```
var address = {id: 100, name: "Gregg", addressOne: "111 1st Street"};
```

And an HTML form:

```
<input id="name" />
<input id="addressOne" />
```

I want to know if there is a way to iterate over all the INPUT elements of the form, and set their values based on the JSON object's properties. The following is the long approach I could take:

```
$.each($("input"), function(idx, input) {
   if (input.attr("id") == "name") input.val( address.name );
   if (input.attr("id") == "addressOne") input.val( address.addressOne );
});
```

I want to know if there is a way to do the above without the IF statements.  Is there some way in JavaScript to dynamically map the two together.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Shouldn't `address` be an `Object` not an `Array`?

Comment: maybe try something like `input.val(address[input.id])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `val` method:

```
$('input').val(function(i, v){
    return address[this.id]
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GKUMk/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#name").val(address.name);
$("#addressOne").val(address.addressOne);
```

Comment: I thought about it, but what happens if you add more inputs and values inside the object address? This works for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($("input"), function(idx, input) {
   if (address[input.attr("id")]) {
       address[input.attr("id")]
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val(address[this.id]);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/olujel/4/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would work, but I redefine the var address to a JSON object.

```
var address = {id: 100, name: "Gregg", addressOne: "111 1st Street"}
```

And the iterator could be:

```
$.each($("input"), function(idx, input) {
    $(this).val( address[input.id] );
});​
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="addressOne" />

var address = { id: 100, name: "Gregg", addressOne: "111 1st Street" },
prop, $field;

for ( prop in address ) {
    $( "#" + prop ).val( address[prop] );
}
```

Note the address variable is now an object literal rather than an array.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/Gt9ND/